# Can't get Grails application to run on Windows 7

Tags: grails, netbeans, windows-7

I'm having trouble running Grails on my PC (running Windows 7).

It's been a couple of years since I last worked with Grails, and I have a new computer. So I downloaded Grails and NetBeans and followed the instructions. (Grails: version 2.3.7, NetBeans: version 7.4.)

Everything seems to be working. Both the Java JDK and Grails work - I can run "grails" from the command prompt. And it was easy to activate the support for Grails in NetBeans.

I created a very simple "Hello world" application. It compiles fine - and I can run "grails war" to create a War file. But I can't get it to run on my PC. I get the same error using "Run" in NetBeans and when running "grails run-app" at the command prompt:

```
|Running Grails application
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files\Grails
\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

And the program won't start. The jar in question isn't missing, so I can't see what's wrong. Any ideas? I'd be more than grateful for some help! :-)

/Anders from Sweden

Comment: move grails do c:\ and try again

Comment: Ah - so it was that easy... Java/Tomcat ought to handle %20-syntax, but apperantly not in that context. It works now - thanks! :-)

Comment: @baxxabit Why don't you write your comment as the answer...

Comment: @UglySwede could you please accept the answer if it's correct

Comment: Ah, sorry - forgot that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your copy of **grails** to `C:\` and try again.

There is a known problem with location with space symbol. You can see it in stacktrace:

```
C:\Program%20Files\...
```